# Set minimum resolution of Unity standalone Windows build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a neat way of setting a minimum resolution for Unity standalone build for Windows.

Unity version: 2019.1.2f1

Currently using following inside Update:

```
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
if (Screen.width < 800 || Screen.height < 450)
   Screen.SetResolution(800, 450, false);
#endif
```

Comment: Is the resolution 800, 450 a fixed one (you do not want the players to resize the window) or is it the minimum? If it is minimum, there seems to be no other option.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. There's no other way to set the minimal resolution.

**But you must move it out of Update loop**. It is quite not performant to call it all frames, and I do not see valid situations where a resolution might change by itself at runtime.

I would suggest to place the script into the `Awake` of a `MonoBehaviour` in the first scene of your game.

```
public class ResolutionStarer : MonoBehaviour
{
     private void Awake()
     {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
         if (Screen.width < 800 || Screen.height < 450)
            Screen.SetResolution(800, 450, false);
#endif
     }
}
```

You might also give a look at [this script](https://github.com/GiacomoMariani/JReact/blob/master/Screen/J_ScreenResolutions.cs) (of a MIT library) that deals with resolutions, and offer you further options, such as changing resolution or set the game windowed.

Still, for the sake of this question they use the same check against `Screen.width` and `Screen.height` to avoid going below `_minWidth` and `_minHeight` resolutions. And they use the same method `Screen.SetResolution` to set the resolution.